# How to draw the picture in the kivy

Tags: android, python, user-interface, kivy

Suppose I have a picture that I keep in ScatterLayout, and I need to paint this picture does not fit the screen coordinates, and the coordinates most pictures. It is also necessary that this inscription has changed along with the picture when you move it around the screen.

Comment: Paste some minimal working example and explain more what do you actually ask.

Comment: Please edit your question to be more clear about what you're asking and provide a minimal, complete, and verifiable example (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)